# What is the correct way how to create "production" build using typescript and node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, build

I am using nodejs and typescript in my project.

I would like to create production build.

I have script to compile all `.ts` into `.js` (`dist` folder).

After build, I would like to upload this `dist` folder into my server (now without docker, etc...).

On server I would like to call `node dist/main.js` for start.

Problem is `node_modules` folder, because there are a lot of `devDependencies` packages. How can I remove `non production` packages before upload `node_modules` into my server?

Comment: Either [prune](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune) the deps, if you're uploading node_modules/, or do a --production  install on the server.

Comment: `ng build --prod`    For Angular Project

Comment: Do you thing that is better to upload node_modules or install it fresh modules on the server?

Comment: The latter, particularly if the server is a different OS to the build environment. I'd use npm ci to use the lock file for consistency.